# Unable to update multiple Elasticsearch fields

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql, elasticsearch-painless

I have an elasticsearch index where one of the fields responsible for vectore search (KNN) has mapping like this:

```
"text_embeddings.predicted_value": {
              "type": "dense_vector",
              "dims": 384,
              "index": true,
              "similarity": "cosine"
            }
```

Other than this, there is a completely different field called "zipData" that has mapping as mentioned below:

```
"zipData": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "zipDistribution": {
                        "type": "nested",
                        "properties": {
                            "zip": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            },
                            "priceData": {
                                "type": "object"
                            },
                            "offerDetails": {
                                "type": "object"
                            },
                            "flags": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "itemStatus": {
                                        "type": "keyword"
                                    },
                                    "itemMessage": {
                                        "type": "keyword"
                                    },
                                    "itemMessageColor": {
                                        "type": "keyword"
                                    },
                                    "popularityScore": {
                                        "type": "integer"
                                    },
                                    "popluarityMessage": {
                                        "type": "keyword"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

I have used the below query to update these fields. For a non vector index it has always run fine, but I have been coming across this issue only for this particulae index with the vectors in it.

```
{
    "script": {
        "source": "for (int i = 0; i < ctx._source.zipData.zipDistribution.size(); i++) { if (ctx._source.zipData.zipDistribution[i].zip == params.zip) { ctx._source.zipData.zipDistribution[i].flags.itemStatus = params.itemStatus; } }",
        "lang": "painless",
        "params": {
            "zip": "55311",
            "itemStatus": "",
            "itemMessage": null,
            "itemMessageColor": null
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when I try to update the above fields by means of that one query, it does not let me do it, and throws the below error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "document_parsing_exception",
                "reason": "[1:10365] failed to parse: Field [text_embedding.predicted_value] of type [dense_vector] doesn't not support indexing multiple values for the same field in the same document"
            }
        ],
        "type": "document_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "[1:10365] failed to parse: Field [text_embedding.predicted_value] of type [dense_vector] doesn't not support indexing multiple values for the same field in the same document",
        "caused_by": {
            "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason": "Field [text_embedding.predicted_value] of type [dense_vector] doesn't not support indexing multiple values for the same field in the same document"
        }
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

Comment: Even something like a simple update query does not work like:

```
{
    "doc": {
        "intField": 49
    }
}
```

I keep getting the same error:
"Field [text_embedding.predicted_value] of type [dense_vector] doesn't not support indexing multiple values for the same field in the same document"

Comment: Do you have an ingest pipeline configured in your index settings that populates the `text_embeddings.predicted_value`?

Comment: Yes sir!! It maps the vectors from the text in the field "searchField". Here's the snnipet 

es.ingest.put_pipeline(id=pipeline_id, processors=[{
        "inference": {
          "model_id": "sentence-transformers__all-minilm-l6-v2",
          "target_field": "text_embedding",
          "field_map": {
            "searchField": "text_field"
          }
        }
      }])

Comment: And here's my _settings setup

{
    "number_of_replicas": "1",
    "default_pipeline": "knn_vector_search",
    "index.max_inner_result_window": 1000000,
    "index.mapping.nested_objects.limit": 2000000,
    "index.max_result_window": 10000000
}

Comment: The pipeline-id is "knn_vector_search"

Comment: Is any further action needed on this?

Comment: I could not reproduce your case so far, I'm trying to figure out how that's possible

Comment: Ok. Basically, I am trying to update a certain field in that index which has no relation with the text_embedding field but still it throws this error. 

"Field [text_embedding.predicted_value] of type [dense_vector] doesn't not support indexing multiple values for the same field in the same document"

Even a simple  _update query is not working!

Comment: I've understood your issue, that's what you've stated in your question. Just trying to wrap my head around it.

Comment: Ok. Waiting to hear from you. Let me know if these resources are related - 

https://www.shubho.dev/devops/elastic-search-update-by-query-with-ingest-pipeline/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51303768/ingest-pipeline-for-create-update-document-dates

Comment: Any progress in this sir?